# How to run job in multiple slave node in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to run jenkins same job on multiple node. I have create same label name in my all node, but when running pipeline jenkins run job only on one of them. Can anyone have solution ?

Comment: This question is unclear. Could you paste the Jenkins file snippet? Do you want to distribute the load among different agents or you would like to duplicate the same job execution on different agents?

Comment: i would like to duplicate the same job execution on different agents

Comment: There is no out of the box support for this in Jenkins. However, you can handle it inside a Jenkins file or by creating a new jenkinsfile and configuring it in Jenkins. Lets say `jenkinsfile` for `node1` and `jenkinsfile2` for `node2`. Or you can add branching in the jenkinsfile itself.